# Which section should be first? Upstream and downstream sections

Tags: contract-design

Well... I have a problem of starting writing smart contract in with I don't know which part should be written first.
For example we have a game. It has a hero and it has some functions like fighting and etc. The contracts are for example Account, Hero and Fighting contract. Should it be written like this:
Account -> Hero -> Fighting or Fighting -> Hero -> Account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very generic and therefore very hard to answer. Id say it completely depends on you and your project. I know writing multiple smart contracts that interact with eachother can be a pain (im struggling with a few at the moment lol). In your example id write fighting first, then hero and then account, since fighting should have less calls to make to the 2 others. In the case where you're forced to make a call to a function from a function you didnt write yet id use a placeholder or a comment, kinda like this (this is pseudo ofc)

```
contract Fighting {
function attack (address attacker, address defender, uint256 attackerStat, uint256 defenderStat) public {
    uint256 damageDealt = attackerStat - defenderStat // (or whatever math you want to perform to get the damage dealt. btw using solidity's native - operator is unsafe, use SafeMath's sub() function instead
    // HeroContract defender = HeroContract(defender)
    // defender.looseHP(damageDealt)
    // The 2 last lines are commented out because you didnt write the hero contract yet, and you're not sure you'll use that exact syntax. 
}
```

}